# 0 is null or not an object error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Am using the following javascript programm for convert pdf file to binary file .It will work properly in FireFox.but in IE it will display the "0 is null or not an object javascript" .how to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#document_upload').change(function()
  {
   var fileList = this.files;
   var file = fileList[0];
   create_blob(file,function(blob_string)
   {
    replace_binary_data=blob_string;
    $("#document_binary").val(replace_binary_data);
   }); 
  });    


        function create_blob(file, callback) 
  {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function()
   { 
    callback(reader.result) 

   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }  


    });

</script>    

<body>

    <input type="text" id="document_binary" value=""/>
    <div id="upload_document">
        <input type="file" name="document"  id="document_upload"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure IE does not support `FileReader` (so you cannot instantiate it for obvious reasons).

See http://caniuse.com/filereader - it is not available until IE10.